# Create indexes for tables with prefix in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I'm trying to achieve a way to create multiple indexes for multiple tables in Postgresql.

For now, i wrote something like this

```
do $$

declare temprow record;
declare idx_name character varying(200);

begin

for temprow in
    select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public' and table_name like 'prefix%' order by table_name
loop
    idx_name := 'index_name_prefix_' || temprow.table_name || '_idx';
    create index idx_name ON temprow.table_name (column1 asc, column2 desc);
end loop;

end$$;
```

Seems like this should work, but it doesn't with an error

```
ERROR:  schema "temprow" does not exist
```

I thought i would just schedule this sql once a week, as that's a proper way for my task

Can you help me to find error in this SQL or suggest a better way to create indexes for multiple tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have `create index idx_name ON temprow.table_name`, the table name ***must*** be a real table, not a variable with a string containing the table name, or any other indirect way of dynamically/indirectly referencing a table's name.

- Where you have `temprow.table_name` the syntax expects `schema.table`
- So, you're telling PostgreSQL to create the index on the table `table_name` in the schema `temprow`

What you're looking for is ***Dynamic SQL***; that is code that writes SQL as a string, and then separately executing that string.

```
DO $do$

DECLARE 
  temprow  RECORD;
  sql_stmt CHARACTER VARYING(1024);
BEGIN

  FOR temprow IN
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name like 'prefix%' ORDER BY table_name
  LOOP
    sql_stmt := FORMAT(
                  'create index index_name_prefix_%s_idx ON %s (column1 asc, column2 desc);',
                  temprow.table_name,
                  temprow.table_name
                );

    EXECUTE(sql_stmt);

  END LOOP;

END $do$;
```

Working example:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b50edb9de4db420b20e09e8221e4ce4a

***Do be careful of using this pattern though.***

- It begins to open you up to ***SQL Injection attacks***.

Check out what happens if someone tries to hack you by abusing quoted table names...

- `CREATE TABLE "prefix_z ON test(id); drop table prefix_test; --" (id INT);`
- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4a9abcf2ea8fa87148927b033bde1bd3

Comment: If you use `%I` instead of `%s` in `format()` then this is no longer open to SQL injection: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72183143e7be8a386b1482189a1a2e0c